# Is there an R command to break execution of a chunk and jump to the next one in RStudio?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am grappling with [this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6675) and am trying to think of a smart workaround. One option that I think would work would be to include a line that breaks execution of the chunk without raising an error -- kind of like the equivalent of `break` in a loop. The closest thing I can find is the `stopifnot` command, but it raises an error and thus doesn't execute the rest of the document. Here's an example:

````
---
params:
  eval: false
---

```{r}
print("This is the first line in the first chunk.")
stopifnot(params$eval)
print("This is the second line in the first chunk.")
```

```{r}
print("This is the first line in the second chunk.")
```
````

If I hit "Run All" in RStudio on the above code, it prints "This is the first line in the first chunk" and then an error message. It does not print "This is the second line in the first chunk," which is good. However, I would like it to continue on and print "This is the first line in the second chunk," which does not currently happen.

Thanks!

Comment: you can try error = TRUE on some chunk that you want to stop error checking, but then it will also print the second message

Comment: Why not just do `if(params$eval) {` and add a closing curly bracket at the end of the chunk?

Comment: Aesthetics, mostly =) It just seems like breaking out of a chunk should be an obvious thing to do. Perhaps not.